# SQL cross joining two tables (with common key) to third table with different (common key) for all

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following three tables and key fields

```
Location: location_key
room: location_key, room_key
floor: location_key, floor_key
```

the data looks like

```
location:ABC, Room:location_key,ABC; room_key,1,2,3
location:ABC, Floor:location_key,ABC; floor_key,2,4,5
```

so the output should look like

```
Location:ABC Room:1    floor:null
Location:ABC Room:2    floor:2
Location:ABC Room:3    floor:null
Location:ABC Room:null floor:4
Location:ABC Room:null floor:5
```

I can't seem to get the correct join structure to make this work.
I get the floor populated in the nulls, incorrectly or vis-versa.

Can someone help me with the correct joins structure please

Comment: I suppose you tried to simplify your real data model in order to ask this question? For, if this is really about rooms and floors, then a room would be on a floor, so we'd expect a floor ID in the room table. A room key would never be compared to a floor key, for a room is a room and a floor is a floor. If you want help on your data model, open another request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `FULL OUTER JOIN` and brackets to specify a precedence in the joins:

```sql
SELECT l.location_key,
       f.floor_key,
       r.room_key
FROM   Location l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         room r
         FULL OUTER JOIN floor f
         ON  r.location_key = f.location_key
         AND r.room_key = f.floor_key
       )
       ON (  l.location_key = r.location_key
          OR l.location_key = f.location_key)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE location(location_key) AS
SELECT 'abc' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE floor (location_key, floor_key) AS
SELECT 'abc', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE room(location_key, room_key) AS
SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc', 5 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LOCATION_KEY | FLOOR_KEY | ROOM_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | *null* |
| abc | 2 | 2 |
| abc | 3 | *null* |
| abc | *null* | 4 |
| abc | *null* | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sc5yv8-i)

Comment: this works great, but what i did not include in the original question was, the from is by customer (with millions of entries) and the location is an inner join. where I have; 

FROM Customer
INNER JOIN Location
  LEFT JOIN room .......
  ....
ON customer.cusnum = location.cusnum

if I have just the customer and inner location join, when I want to add a filter in tableau on the customer name, all customers are listed instantly. if I add the next join with the room/floor the query in tableau to add the customer name takes ages to run. I need to have subsequent join based on the customer

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a full outer join of flloors and rooms, so as to not onlyget floor/room matches, but also floors without rooms and rooms without floors.

```
select
  coalesce(f.location_key, r.location_key) as location,
  r.room_key,
  f.floor_key
from room r
full outer join floor f  on f.location_key = r.location_key
                        and f.floor_key    = r.room_key
order by location, r.room_key, f.floor_key;
```

(Comparing floor keys to room keys looks a bit weird, but I guess this is just due to an unfortunate naming choice.)

Comment: Thanks both. fyi without the coalesce, the performance made the first recommendation unusable. once I added the outer join, loading took forever as i am working with a super large db. adding the coalesce solved the performance problem. so i am using a combo of both answers.